# CLion: force the attach process to attach process to certain debugger

Tags: python, clion, lldb

I am trying to debug some c++ codes called from a python program (through python-c++ binding). My original approach was to start ipython, open lldb and attach the ipython process in lldb. Then go to ipython to run my python program. This works fine.

Now I want to take advantages of CLion IDE by attaching the ipython process inside CLion. However, When I did the attach process from CLion, it seems to attach to the process to the pydev debugger like below instead of attach the process to lldb:

```
Attaching to a process with PID=18016
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/Resources/Python.app/Contents/MacOS/Python /Applications/CLion.app/Contents/plugins/python/helpers/pydev/pydevd_attach_to_process/attach_pydevd.py --port 51406 --pid 18016
Connected to pydev debugger (build 183.5429.37)
```

However, I want the process to be attached to lldb, not pydev_debugger.

How do I force the attach_process in CLion to attach the process to lldb instead of pydev_debugger? Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

There must be two entries in the attach dialog corresponding to the target process in question: attach using the pydev debugger and the native debugger. You may try filtering the list by the process PID in order to check that.

Please find a similar report in the CLion issue tracker [here](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/CPP-9386#focus=streamItem-27-2082580.0-0):

> Inside the "Attach to Local Process..." dialog there're two kinds of processes you're able to attach to: one comes from CLion (attach with LLDB or GDB), another is provided by the Python plugin (attach with Python Debugger). Since the process you intend to attach to is a Python interpreter, the latter (the Python debugger) is suggested by default, while you should rather use the former (the CLion debugger) for debugging C/C++ code.